# Django can't quite get the right path

Tags: python, django

I have this view here:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.urls import reverse
from django.template import loader
from django.views.generic import ListView

class IndexView(ListView):
    def get(self, request):
        template_name = loader.get_template('home/blog.html')
        return render(request, template_name)
        return HttpResponse(template_name.render(request))
```

So if I remove          *return render(request, template_name)* everything will be working properly but now when I trying to use *return render(request, template_name)* I get these error:

```
<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x7f13916f46d8>
```

places where Django tried to find the template:

```
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/marton/documents/github/fmi-fall-2016/django/click_bait/miranda/home/templates/<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x7f13916f46d8> (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/marton/documents/github/fmi-fall-2016/django/click_bait/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x7f13916f46d8> (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /home/marton/documents/github/fmi-fall-2016/django/click_bait/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/<django.template.backends.django.Template object at 0x7f13916f46d8> (Source does not exist)
```

What should I do? Now is the time to say that eversince I have started this project I have had problem with paths, half an hour ago for some reason Django was searching in my virtual environment's folder.

Comment: Where is this template? Is the app the template is in added to your INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: path to target html /home/marton/documents/github/fmi-fall-2016/django/click_bait/miranda/home/templates/home/blog.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misunderstanding a few things here. The loader returns a template object, not a template name. You don't need that call to `loader.get_template` at all; you pass the template path directly to render:

```
 return render(request, 'home/blog.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `template_name` should be a string.
It's not, it's the return of the template loader.
You should directly pass 'home/blog.html' as template_name to your render() call.

But with a ListView I suggest you to directly use the `template_name` attribute.

This way :

```
class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'home/blog.html'

    #[...]
```